# Fill a DataGrid from top to down

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, datagrid

I'm creating a DataGrid that is filled by values from a dictionary that contains a string as a key and a List as a value. The key should be the header of the column and the contents of the list were contents of that column:

```
header1(key)     header2(key)      header3(key)
value1fromList   value1fromList    value1fromList
value2fromList   value2fromList    value2fromList   
value3fromList                     value3fromList
```

For that, I'm creating a DataTable that is filled with this values and used as the ItemSource for the DataGrid. My issue is that I don't know how to fill the DataTable this way. My solution just fills the DataTable with some gaps and overwrites existing values.

http://oi64.tinypic.com/20f45eh.jpg

```
public void FillDataGrid(Dictionary<string, List<string>> valuedict)
        {
            myGrid.Columns.Clear();
            var dt = new DataTable();
            DataRow row = null;
            foreach(KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> entry in valuedict)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(entry.Key);
                foreach (string word in entry.Value)
                {
                    row = dt.NewRow();
                    row[entry.Key] = word;
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(row);
            }
            myGrid.ItemsSource = dt.AsDataView();
        }
```

Comment: can you give us an example of what your code produces?  you've shown us what you want.  what do you currently get?

Comment: Added a screenshot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You current code is trying to put non-tabular data into a tabular structure.

You are adding rows to the DataTable before you have created all of the columns.

Your first iteration through your outer foreach loop, you have exactly 1 column (header1).  Then inside your inner foreach loop, you are adding rows to your DataTable that only has one column at that point.  So after your first iteration, your table will look like this:

```
header1    
value1fromList
value2fromList
value3fromList
```

In your second iteration through the outer foreach loop you are adding the second column (header2) and then adding rows to your DataTable that now has 2 columns.

At the end of your second iteration through the outer foreach loop, your table would look like this:

```
    header1           header2      
1)   value1fromList   
2)   value2fromList   
3)   value3fromList   
4)                    value1fromList2
5)                    value2fromList2
```

And when you add header3 to the mix, the data for header3's values would occupy rows 6, 7, and 8.

Now I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but it sounds like you are trying to have a grid that looks like this:

```
     header1(key)     header2(key)      header3(key)
1)   value1fromList   value1fromList    value1fromList
2)   value2fromList   value2fromList    value2fromList   
3)   value3fromList                     value3fromList
```

One way would be to add all of your columns to the table first, and then iterate the largest list adding all 3 columns values to the row at the same time.

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> entry in valuedict)
{
    dt.Columns.Add(entry.Key);
}
```

And then you would iterate the number of items in your largest list adding the values for each column at the same time.

```
int i = 0;
foreach (string word in MyLongestList.Value)
{
    row = dt.NewRow();
    row[firstList.key] = firstList[i];
    row[secondList.key] = secondList[i];
    row[MyLongestList.key] = word;
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
    i++;
}
```

Personally, I don't think the structure of your presentation reflects the data accurately.  You are putting non-tabular data into a tabular structure.  But, it can be done.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is a big help. I understand now how the rows are filled.